# Start Android JUnit from an activity

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I am doing an app that needs to start testing other apps.
The ideea is that you select an app(from a list) and then a test case for it. Eg: you select facebook and then to test the login. A test case for the facebook app starts(using robotium black-box testing).
I created the test and it works fine if I launch it from eclipse as an Android JUnit. However I cannnot start it from my app. I thought that I could start the test using some intent but couldn't(I tried this because I saw the test in Manage Apps->All). I also tried using broadcast receiver - the test app receives the broadcast, but when I try to instantiate the test, the constructor needs to invoke super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, launcherActivityClass); where public static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID = "com.facebook.katana"; public static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity"; and I the app crashes with: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity
Does anyone have any ideea to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and my solution consists of using Java reflection to get an ActivityManagerNative and then invoke its methods to start the tests.

So, my code looks like this:

```
try {
        Class<?> ActivityManagerNative = Class
                .forName("android.app.ActivityManagerNative");
        Log.e("LOADED", "" + ActivityManagerNative);
        Method getDefault = ActivityManagerNative.getMethod("getDefault",
                (Class<?>[]) null);
        Class<?> IActivityManager = Class
                .forName("android.app.IActivityManager");
        Object am = IActivityManager.cast(getDefault.invoke(
                ActivityManagerNative, (Object[]) null));
        Class<?> IInstrumentationWatcher = Class
                .forName("android.app.IInstrumentationWatcher");
        Method startInstrumentation = IActivityManager.getMethod(
                "startInstrumentation", ComponentName.class, String.class,
                Integer.TYPE, Bundle.class, IInstrumentationWatcher);
        ComponentName cn = ComponentName
                .unflattenFromString("your.test.package/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        startInstrumentation.invoke(am, cn, null, 0, bundle, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can't take full credit for the code, I saw something similar somewhere (used for other purposes,) but I can't remember where.

Basically, the code is trying to simulate `runInstrument` from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/com/android/commands/am/Am.java#343).

Cheers,
Silviu